# How to store in a structure anonymous functions generated by a loop in Matlab?

Tags: matlab

I would like to store each anonymous function generated by a Matlab loop in a **structure** (**and not in a cell**) and then access and evaluate each stored anonymous function in another separated loop. I report a very simple example with the cell approach. I don't know which is the most efficient way to use a structure in this context.

```
gammatrue = 2;
deltatrue = -3;
T = 4;
n = 3;
BS = 10;
r = 5;
bsdensdraws = cell(1, BS);
bsdensdrawsev = zeros(T*n*r, BS);

for w = 1:BS
    data = randn(T*n, n-1);
    mutrue = gammatrue/deltatrue*data;   
    sigmatrue = repmat(1/(deltatrue^2)*eye(n-1), [1 1 T*n]);
    draws = mvnrnd(repmat(mutrue, [r 1]), repmat(sigmatrue, [1 1 r])); %matrix (r*T*n)x(n-1))
    bsdensdraws{w} = @(z) mvnpdf(draws,repmat(z(1)/z(2)*data, [r 1]), ...
                       repmat(repmat(1/(z(2)^2)*eye(n-1), [1 1 T*n]), [1 1 r])); 
end

param = [2 3; 4 5; 6 7];
for w = 1:BS
    for y = 1:size(param,1)
        gamma = param(y,1);
        delta = param(y,2);
        bsdensdrawsev(:,w) = bsdensdraws{w}([gamma delta]); %vector (T*n*r)x1 
    end
end
```

Comment: Why do you want to solve this with a structure? A structure is indexed by its field names. You will have to create a cell array containing all field names. You can then find the field name for each iteration and write your function handle there. It is possible, but I don't see any advantages in this.

Comment: I need to use Matlab Coder to convert in C which does not support cell.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to access the fields of a struct by its name, you need to generate a list of field names first. As you only have 10 fields, i suggest

```
fields = char(double('a'):double('a')+BS)'
```

which generates an array containing the letters a to k. You preallocate `bsdensdraws` by

```
bsdensdraws = struct();
```

and write the handles to it by

```
bsdensdraws.(fields(w)) = ...
```

You can access it the same way. If you need more iterations, then you might need a more sophisticated way to generate your field names.

Comment: Thanks! Regarding your sentence "If you need more iterations, then you might need a more sophisticated way to generate your field names", I tried with BS=1000 and it seems to work; am I doing something wrong?

Comment: Ok, very good. I don't think so. That way the field names are not ASCII anymore, but as long as it works I guess it is fine.